# Consolidate array data on unique values

Tags: arrays, swift

In Swift, given a struct containing an int, and a string, is it possible to sum the int, based on the string value (feels like a key, value issue)

given:

```
struct Structure {
    let number: Int
    let text: String
}

var arrayOfStructs: [Structure] = [
    Structure(number: 3, text: "foo"),
    Structure(number: 5, text: "bar"),
    Structure(number: 7, text: "foo")
    ]

arrayOfStructs.count()==3
```

output an array where elements 0 and 2 are effectively ‘summed’ resulting in:

```
arrayOfStructs[0] == Structure(number:10, text: "foo")
arrayOfStructs[1] == Structure(number:5, text: "bar")
arrayOfStructs.count() == 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to reduce the array of structs into a new array where each `text` value occurs once and the `number` value is the sum for the corresponding `text` values.

```
struct Structure{
    let number: Int
    let text: String
}

var arrayOfStructs: [Structure] = [
    Structure(number: 4, text: "A"),
    Structure(number: 2, text: "B"),
    Structure(number: 5, text: "C"),
    Structure(number: 7, text: "A"),
    Structure(number: 3, text: "C"),
    Structure(number: 1, text: "A"),
    Structure(number: 6, text: "C"),
]

let newStructs = arrayOfStructs
                     .reduce(into: [String: Int]()) { $0[$1.text, default: 0] += $1.number }
                     .map { Structure(number: $0.value, text: $0.key) }
print(newStructs)
```

Comment: Swift can infer the dictionary type `reduce(into: [:])`

Comment: `Structure.init` could be shorter

Comment: @LeoDabus Good to know. But personally this is a case I'd rather be explicit from a readability point of view.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I just tried what I think you meant and it doesn't work.

Comment: we could use dictionary initializer as well `let totals: [String: Int] = .init(arrayOfStructs.map {($0.text, $0.number)}, uniquingKeysWith: +)`

Comment: @LeoDabus and what would happen to the order of the array?